# Need help to declare array for plist info retrieval in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

Due to the changes that just happened with the transition from Swift 2 to Swift 3, I am unable to figure out the solution to my code issue on Xcode.

```
 func addBuildingPins(){
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CurtinBuildingList", ofType: "plist")
    let buildings = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: (filePath)!) /*check plist file to see if it is a dictionary or array or else for loop cannot run*/
    for building in buildings!{
        let point = CGPointFromString(building["coordinate"] as! String)
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(point.x), CLLocationDegrees(point.y))
        let title = building["title"] as! String
        let typeRawValue = Int(building["type"] as! String)!
        let type = BuildingType(rawValue: typeRawValue)
        let subtitle = building["subtitle"] as! String
        let annotation = BuildingAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate, title: title, subtitle: subtitle, type: type!)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        print(building)
    }
}
```

The error is just before the square brackets (building[]). The error I keep getting is

> Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka, Any) has no subscript members".

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Wait so are you storing an array of arrays in your plist?

Comment: Yea. I was just following a guide on navigation functionality for Swift and so my plist contains an array of arrays. Each of the minor arrays contains info on a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

Convert you buildings array to `[[String: Any]]` before using for loop.

```
if let array = buildings as? [[String: Any]] {
     for building in array {
          //Your code 
     }
}
```